# “Command not found” error in the installation process

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, installation, apt

**Why I receive the following error while trying to install this package? and how can I resolve it?**

```
root@me-System-Product-Name:/home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master# ls
AUTHORS    configure.ac  INSTALL  Makefile.am  README  TODO
ChangeLog  COPYING       LICENSE  NEWS         src     tools
root@me-System-Product-Name:/home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master# ./Makefile.am 
./Makefile.am: line 1: SUBDIRS: command not found
./Makefile.am: line 3: style:: command not found
```

Note that I already searched for `SUBDIRS` and `style` packages, but I found nothing.

I also tried `apt-get`, but same result:

```
root@me-System-Product-Name:/home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master# apt-get install SUBDIRS
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package SUBDIRS
root@me-System-Product-Name:/home/me/Desktop/mfcuk-master# apt-get install style
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package style
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands to install it. I cloned it as well and looked in Makefile.am but there is no indication of packages `SUBDIRS` or `style`:

```
automake
autoconf
./configure
make
```